# XML cannot find the declaration of element

Tags: xml

Hello I'm still kinda new to XML, and while I did look around for this problem the answers I found didn't quite fit with my issue. When I validate this xml it comes up with the error "Cannot find the declaration of element 'sites' ". I can't seem to figure out what is going on exactly and I was curious if anyone could help.

XML below

```
  <sites xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:xsi="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/site"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/site  sites.xsd">

    <xs:import namespace="http://sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
         schemaLocation="http://sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9sitemap.xsd" />
```

XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:cc="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites"
xmlns:sm="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
targetNamespace="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites"
elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

<xs:element name="sites">
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="site" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
           <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                 <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                 <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="totalPages"/>
                </xs:sequence>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems:

- `sites` is not recognised because the schema declares that `elementFormDefault="qualified"` - this means that elements in the schema are in the schema's target namespace. `<sites>` declares an element in the global namespace - `<sites>` and `<prefix:sites>` are **different elements**. Create a namespace prefix and use it to qualify the `<sites>` element in your instance document to fix this error.
- `<sites>` is not closed - this is not well-formed XML, assuming this is your whole document.

In answer to your followup comment:
`<xs:sites>` is not correct, because the prefix `xs` is declared as a prefix for `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`. `<sites>` is not in this namespace - it's in `http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites`. So to add a new namespace prefix, add an attribute `xmlns:prefix="http://example.com/weekendfunsnacks/sites"` to the `sites` element, then use *that* prefix on the `sites` element.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your input! I had fixed a few things regarding the code. I have gave the  `<site>`  a prefix. Though when I gave the prefix it gave me an error stating "The prefix of "xs" for element "xs:sites" is not bound. Would it be because I gave it the "xs" prefix? I was told

" In the sites.xml file, add a namespace declaration to the root sites element, associating the xs prefix with the URI for the XML Schema namespace. " Would it be wrong to do so?

Sorry if this seems like added information or as an unrelated question